# using an "isolated DC/DC converter", what is the schematic?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to use a "isolated DC/DC converter" (5v --> 12v converter)

(MEE3S0512SC, http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata/MEE3S0512SC/?qs=%2fha2pyFadugniRNbNhQpOV6aGeFGH%2fTBs%252bIW10C7AdACaF1cHtE9jQ%3d%3d)

Reading the data sheet, I've connected as such:

pin 1 (Vin-): +5v DC from power supply

pin 2 (Vin+): GND from power supply

pin 3 (Vout-): voltmeter GND

pin 4 (Vout+): voltmeter +

I'm reading 30V on the voltmeter. What am I doing incorrectly?

Many thanks in advance,
Matthew

Comment: Do you have any load on the output?  Try adding a 100 Ohm resistor across the output and read the voltage again.

Comment: You have the input polarity wrong.  Pin 1 should connect to the negative side of your power supply, and Pin 2 to the +5V side.  I'm surprised that you get anything out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've actually connected pins 1 & 2 the correct way around, then have a look at the 'Output Voltage Tolerance Envelope' graph at the top of page 2 of the datasheet.
You'll notice that it doesn't show anything for an output load current of less than 10% of its max rated output.

I take this to mean that this DC-DC converter *needs* to have at least some load connected before it will correctly regulate its output voltage.

In this case a 470 ohm resistor should just suffice.

Comment: thank you so much... this works. but could you also explain how you arrived at the 470 ohm answer?

Comment: The Output Voltage Tolerance graph implies a minimum load requirement of 10% of rated output current.  The rated current is 250 mA, and the 470 ohm resistor will draw 25 mA.  I find it odd that the datasheet doesn't explicitly state a minimum load.  Many switching supplies do require a minimum load to regulate correctly.

Comment: I like to add an LED (and series resistor) that uses this minimum current for those cases when the load can be switched off ... I just hate thinking about that wasted energy so I get it doing something useful.